# How do Common Names (CN) and Subject Alternative Names (SAN) work together?

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Assuming the Subject Alternative Name (SAN) property of an SSL certificate contains two DNS names

1. `domain.example`
2. `host.domain.example`

but the Common Name (CN) is set to only one of both: `CN=domain.example`.

- Does this setup have a special meaning, or any [dis]advantages over setting both CNs?
- What happens on server-side if the other one, `host.domain.example`, is being requested?

Specifically, how does *OpenSSL 0.9.8b+* handle the given scenario?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This depends on implementation, but the general rule is that the domain is checked against all SANs and the common name. If the domain is found there, then the certificate is OK for connection.

[RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.6), section 4.1.2.6 says "The subject name MAY be carried in the subject field and/or the subjectAltName extension". This means that the domain name must be checked against both SubjectAltName extension and Subject property (namely its common name parameter) of the certificate. These two places complement each other, not duplicate each other. And SubjectAltName is a proper place to put additional names, such as *www*.domain.example or *www2*.domain.example

Update: as per [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.4), published in 2011, the validator must check SAN first, and if SAN exists, then CN should not be checked. Note that RFC 6125 is relatively recent and there still exist certificates and CAs that issue certificates, which include the "main" domain name in CN and alternative domain names in SAN. In other words, by excluding CN from validation if SAN is present, you can deny some otherwise valid certificate.

Comment: Is this short-circuit generally? I mean, SANs are always checked first and if found, the CN is not being checked at all?

Comment: If you're dealing with IE, it appears to ignore the CN if the subjectAltName is present.  I've seen both IE10 and IE8 complain about mismatched name in cases like that.

Comment: @Eric I think this depends on the version of the backend library that does certificate validation (CryptoAPI modules), rather than on IE itself.

Comment: This is incorrect with regards to SSL certificates. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25971071/918406) answer for details. TL;DR RFC 5280 is only general for PKI structures. RFC2818 and RFC5216 (for HTTPS) states that if the SAN is present then it MUST be used for identity.

Comment: @JonoCoetzee I don't see how 5216 is related to HTTPS. As for CNs -- unfortunately for standards there exist CAs which put one of the names to CN and another one to SAN. I.e. while you are theoretically correct, practically your approach will lead to certificates not being accepted by the client, and this is not always desired. So the validator must check both to ensure compatibility.

Comment: @JonoCoetzee Also if you refer to RFC 6125, it's dated March '2011 and the question itself is dated May'2011. At the time of writing there were plenty of certificates not compatible with RFC 6125.

Comment: @Eugene Mayevski 'EldoS Corp Yeah sorry RFC5216 isn't for HTTPS, got them confused. Regardless Chrome will now throw ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID error since it uses the SAN exclusively (if present).

Comment: And now officially, Chrome won't check the CN attribute anymore.  My thought is maybe the fields should match the function within the cert a bit better.

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4981025180483584

Answer (score 53):

To be absolutely correct you should put all the names into the SAN field.

The CN field should contain a Subject Name not a domain name, but when the Netscape found out this SSL thing, they missed to define its greatest market.
Simply there was not certificate field defined for the Server URL.

This was solved to put the domain into the CN field, and nowadays usage of the CN field is deprecated, but still widely used.
The CN can hold only one domain name.

The general rules for this:
CN - put here your main URL (for compatibility)
SAN - put all your domain here, repeat the CN because its not in right place there, but its used for that...

If you found a correct implementation, the answers for your questions will be the followings:

- Has this setup a special meaning, or any [dis]advantages over setting both CNs?
  You cant set both CNs, because CN can hold only one name.
  You can make with 2 simple CN certificate instead one CN+SAN certificate, but you need 2 IP addresses for this.
- What happens on server-side if the other one, host.domain.tld, is being requested?
  It doesn't matter whats happen on server side.

In short:
When a browser client connects to this server, then the browser sends encrypted packages, which are encrypted with the public key of the server. Server decrypts the package, and if server can decrypt, then it was encrypted for the server.

The server doesn't know anything from the client before decrypt, because only the IP address is not encrypted trough the connection. This is why you need 2 IPs for 2 certificates. (Forget SNI, there is too much XP out there still now.)

On client side the browser gets the CN, then the SAN until all of the are checked. 
If one of the names matches for the site, then the URL verification was done by the browser. 
(im not talking on the certificate verification, of course a lot of ocsp, crl, aia request and answers travels on the net every time.)

Answer (score 18):

## CABForum Baseline Requirements

I see no one has mentioned the section in the Baseline Requirements yet. I feel they are important.

**Q:** SSL - How do Common Names (CN) and Subject Alternative Names (SAN) work together?
**A:** Not at all. If there are SANs, then CN can be ignored. -- At least if the software that does the checking adheres very strictly to the CABForum's Baseline Requirements.

(So this means I can't answer the "Edit" to your question. Only the original question.)

[CABForum Baseline Requirements, v. 1.2.5 (as of 2 April 2015), page 9-10](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/BRv1.2.5.pdf#page=17):

> **9.2.2 Subject Distinguished Name Fields**
> **a. Subject Common Name Field**
> **Certificate Field:** subject:commonName (OID 2.5.4.3)
> **Required/Optional:** Deprecated (Discouraged, but not prohibited)
> **Contents:** If present, this field MUST contain a single IP address or Fully-Qualified Domain Name that is one of the values contained in the Certificate’s subjectAltName extension (see Section 9.2.1).

#### EDIT: Links from @Bruno's comment

**RFC 2818:** *HTTP Over TLS*, 2000, [Section 3.1: Server Identity](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1):

> If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST
> be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name
> field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although
> the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and
> Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.

**RFC 6125:** *Representation and Verification of Domain-Based Application Service
Identity within Internet Public Key Infrastructure Using X.509 (PKIX)
Certificates in the Context of Transport Layer Security (TLS)*, 2011, [Section 6.4.4: Checking of Common Names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.4):

> [...] if and only if the presented identifiers do not include a
> DNS-ID, SRV-ID, URI-ID, or any application-specific identifier types
> supported by the client, then the client MAY as a last resort check
> for a string whose form matches that of a fully qualified DNS domain
> name in a Common Name field of the subject field (i.e., a CN-ID).

## Nice to know: Chrome threw out CN support years ago in 2017

Update added 2023-04-27.

- Summary blog post: https://xenit.se/blog/2018/04/08/chrome-certificate-warning-invalid-common-name/
- *"Intent to Remove: Support for commonName matching in certificates
  2"*: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/security-dev/c/IGT2fLJrAeo/m/csf_1Rh1AwAJ
- *"Issue 308330: Remove support for common names in certificates; only support Subject Alt Names"* https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=308330

Comment: This CABForum Baseline Requirement rule isn't very useful technically. It just tells you what to put in the CN, but it certainly doesn't mean that the CN is used for verification anyway. It makes sense to have the CN to be one of the SANs, but that's mostly useful for tools and administrative purposes (or against implementation that are too relaxed). From a verification point of view, RFC 2818 ("*If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST be used as the identity*"), and even RFC 6125, largely predate that specification, and that particular rule is still valid in both.

Comment: Next update Nov. 2023:
"The server identity can only be expressed in the subjectAltNames extension; it is **no longer valid to use the commonName** RDN, known as CN-ID in [VERIFY]."
[RFC9525, Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9525#appendix-A-2.2) which obsoletes RFC 6125.