# Hyperledger Fabric CA: x509: certificate is valid for rca-ord, not localhost

Tags: hyperledger-fabric-ca

we have started an instance of fabric-ca-server with following settings in docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

networks:
  test:

services:

  myservice:
    container_name: my-container
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    command: /bin/bash -c "fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw"
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_CN=rca-ord
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_HOSTS=rca-ord
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_DEBUG=true
    volumes:
      - ./scripts:/scripts
      - ./data:/data
    networks:
      - test
    ports:
      - 7054:7054
```

but when we try to enroll a user against this server using the command below:

```
root@fd85cc416f52:/# fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://user:userpw@localhost:7054 --tls.certfiles $FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME/tls-cert.pem
```

we get the error below:

```
2018/12/08 22:18:03 [INFO] TLS Enabled
2018/12/08 22:18:03 [INFO] generating key: &{A:ecdsa S:256}
2018/12/08 22:18:03 [INFO] encoded CSR
Error: POST failure of request: POST https://localhost:7054/enroll
{"hosts":["fd85cc416f52"],"certificate_request":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\nMIIBQDCB6AIBADBcMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEXMBUGA1UECBMOTm9ydGggQ2Fyb2xp\nbmExFDASBgNVBAoTC0h5cGVybGVkZ2VyMQ8wDQYDVQQLEwZGYWJyaWMxDTALBgNV\nBAMTBHVzZXIwWTATBgcqhkjOPQIBBggqhkjOPQMBBwNCAATREdPvOeaWG9TzaEyk\nhFXRnJFJouDXShr0D1745bCt/0n3qjpqviZiApd1t62VrpMX0j8DBa6tkF7C+rEr\nRvwnoCowKAYJKoZIhvcNAQkOMRswGTAXBgNVHREEEDAOggxmZDg1Y2M0MTZmNTIw\nCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIDRwAwRAIgASXupobxJia/FFlLiwYzYpacvSA6RiIc/LR/kvdB\nT8ICIA1nJ2RfHrwMhOWocxMAIuLUsBvKS3S5DIwCHp0/gBpn\n-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----\n","profile":"","crl_override":"","label":"","NotBefore":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","NotAfter":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z","CAName":""}: Post https://localhost:7054/enroll: x509: certificate is valid for rca-ord, not localhost
```

on the server-side we can see following message printed out when the request is sent:

```
my-container | 2018/12/08 22:18:03 http: TLS handshake error from 127.0.0.1:56518: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

we have also tried:

```
root@fd85cc416f52:/# ls $FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME
IssuerPublicKey  IssuerRevocationPublicKey  ca-cert.pem  fabric-ca-server-config.yaml  fabric-ca-server.db  msp  tls-cert.pem
root@fd85cc416f52:/# fabric-ca-client enroll -u https://user:userpw@localhost:7054 --tls.certfiles $FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME/ca-cert.pem
```

with same result

wondering if someone can help us what is wrong here and how can we fix it? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have generated a TLS certificate on the server using `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_HOSTS=rca-ord`, but then you are sending your request to `localhost` in the URL you specify in the enroll command.

To get this to work, you should change your environment variable to also include 'localhost'. For example: `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_HOSTS=rca-ord,localhost`.

Delete the old TLS certificate and generate a new one, and it should work.

Comment: tried and doesn't work. the error this time is my-container | 2018/12/19 21:53:09 [INFO] 127.0.0.1:57750 POST /enroll 401 23 "Failed to get user: : scode: 404, code: 63, msg: Failed to get User: sql: no rows in result set". why is it trying to get a user when we are asking it to enroll one for the first time?

Comment: That seems like a separate issue. Adding the localhost has gotten past you the TLS handshake error that your original post was about.

Comment: @morpheus did u find any solution? I'm facing the same issue of  `certificate is valid for rca-ord, not localhost `

Comment: I've added `FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_HOSTS` in my `docker-compose.yaml` file under `ca-server` section but it is not working. I haven't generated the new certs.

Comment: @alpha generate new cert and make sure the SAN (Subject Alternative Name) in the cert matches the string you are using to connect to the server. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5937270/147530:
Update: as per RFC 6125, published in '2011 the validator must check SAN first, and if SAN exists, then CN should not be checked.

Comment: Thanks, @morpheus I have a question that when I'm running the ``` fabric-ca-client enroll -u "http://admin:adminpw@localhost:7054" ``` command resulting in some cacerts and signcerts. when I checked the `CN` and `SAN` in signcerts then they both are different. `CN` is `admin` and `SAN` is `MY-MACHINE-NAME` . I have added `localhost` and `abc.com` under  `hosts` in `CSR` section of `fabric-ca-server` config file. is there any way to change the `SAN` to `abc.com`

Comment: use the --csr.hosts flag when running fabric-ca-client enroll to set the SAN. https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABC-831